# Spring MVC preparing JSON but loading a page instead

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, gson

I have a controller to send back a JSON Payload

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/MerchantMonitoringAPI", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json") 
public String MerchantMonitoring() {

    ApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");

        TopMerchantsDAO topMerchantsDAO = (TopMerchantsDAO) context.getBean("topMerchantsDAO");
        TopMerchants topMerchants = topMerchantsDAO.retrieveMerchantList();

        for(String temp:topMerchants.getMerchantList())
        {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<TopMerchants>() {}.getType();

        String jsonPayload = gson.toJson(topMerchants, type);
        System.out.println(jsonPayload);

        return jsonPayload;
}
```

It is trying to redirect me to a view with the page name as the JSON (localhost:8080/{"merchantList":["Apple","Google"]}.jsp)

How to stop this and return the JSON payload ??

Comment: can you add this @RestController on top of the RequestMapping ?

Comment: @georgesvan that worked!

Comment: Nice. Feel free to validate my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add @RestController on top of the @RequestMapping

```
    @RestController 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/MerchantMonitoringAPI", method = 
    RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json") 
    public String MerchantMonitoring() {...}
```

Because the method is now annotated with `@RestController`, the objects returned from this methods will go through message conversion to produce a json resource representation for the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have several methods for returning **JSON** and **page** in the same class, you can still annotate your class with `@Controller`, and the method for JSON annotated with `@ResponseBody`

If you will annotated class with `@RestController` - all methods inside class will be working like `@ResponseBody` and class will be like @Controller annotated. Of course, this is a better approach (to not include page and JSON returning methods in one Controller).

**Notice!** You can use `@RestController` only for class (instead of `@Controller`), not for methods.
If you will open source of this annotation, you will see among other things the next:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public @interface RestController {
    String value() default "";
}
```

and `ElementType.TYPE` has comment:

> Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration